# Can I move guild member to a voice channel if they aren't in one already?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to move a member to a voice channel when they type in a certain command in a text channel. I have the functionality working to move a member to different voice channels, but it only works if they are already in a voice channel. I want to be able to move a member to a voice channel even if they are not currently in one. If they are not in any voice channel I get an error. The error is "Target user is not connected to voice."

Unfortunately I haven't found much info online about that error.

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
  let args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');

  switch (args[0]) {    
    case 'move':
      const members = msg.channel.members.map(member => (member));
      const channel = members[0].guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'test' && channel.type === 'voice');
      members[0].setVoiceChannel(channel.id);
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: I believe that is a limitation of Discord itself - they must connect to a voice channel manually. You can always make a lobby voice channel and require them to connect there first.

Comment: interesting, thanks for the info

Comment: I agree with @vikarjramun. This is not possible due to Discord API limitations

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot "force" a user to join a voice channel. You never will be able to either because that would be a huge breach of personal security. To have a bot automatically join you to a voice channel could be abused by malicious bots. I'm not saying that your bot is malicious, but others are. It's simply not possible.